# Understanding Javascript scoping and variables

Tags: javascript

I've embarked on a mission to actually explore and try to deeply understand Javascript.  On my journey I've come up with the following code and I'm troubled by the output, especially since I can't seem to explain its output yet it throws no errors:

```
var test = 1;
var func = function(){
    console.log(test);
    for(x=0;x!=1;x++) {
        var test = test + x;
        console.log(test);
    };
};
console.log(test);
func();
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
1
1
1   (or possibly an error due to scoping issues)
```

What I actually get is:

```
1
undefined
NaN
```

I can buy the NaN since, in my mind, I've locally scoped a variable named `test` and I'm initializing it to itself plus x.  I could see that as an obvious fail, yet no error is thrown.  The one that really puzzles me is the "undefined."  Shouldn't that output the globally scoped `test`?

Comment: Basically, assigned functions won't get parent scope.

Comment: Araymer: that doesn't make sense.  Clearly, even assigned functions will have global variables in scope; otherwise there's no point in globally scoping something!  The problem is precisely what @Thomas explains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is *function scoped*, not block scoped. Furthermore, `var` declarations are *hoisted* to the top of the function definition. So your code is equivalent to this:

```
var test = 1;
var func = function(){
    var test;
    console.log(test);
    for(x=0;x!=1;x++) {
        test = test + x;
        console.log(test);
    };
};
console.log(test);
func();
```

This is why some people (e.g. Doug Crockford, author of jslint) advocate always putting declarations at the top of the function, because that's how the interpreter reads them anyway.

Comment: Ahhh... Thank you Thomas!  That makes sense.

Comment: I agree with David Hoelzer.  One more comment is the variable x in this function is a global variable.  By not having a var x, you may be stepping onto some global variable.

Comment: Oh, that's super important.  Thanks @Will.  I was unaware of that.

Comment: Strict mode will help you catch such mistakes by requiring that every variable be declared.